# Flutter crashes on start when applying Firebase Analytics(FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I connect Firebase to Android but when using Firebase Analytics the Flutter app crashes.

---

```
  firebase_core: ^2.10.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.2.0
```

> This is my code for running **Firebase** put in the main start :
>
> ```
> // ...
>   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
>   await Firebase.initializeApp(
>     options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
>   );
>   FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
> ```

My error :

```
): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(14198): Process:  PID: 14198
E/AndroidRuntime(14198): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.v2.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@21.2.2:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.V1.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@21.2.2:26)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.V1.G(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@21.2.2:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk@@21.2.2:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.l0.a(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.2.2:15)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.t0.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.2.2:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.i.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:272)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.lang.Enum.-$$Nest$smenumValues(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:279)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:291)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2461)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:754)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at R2.c.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@21.2.2:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    at R2.c.<clinit>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@21.2.2:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(14198):    ... 9 more
```